# Node.js watch a directory for incoming archive by scp

Tags: javascript, node.js, scp, watch, fs

I have a task to create a node.js script that listens in a directory for new archive files to arrive and process them.

I see that I can do this with `fs.watch`.

The files are `tar.gz` archives, that arrive via `scp`.

The problem is that the arrival of a new archive file seems to create multiple (the exact number is unpredictable) events in the file-system. The first is a `rename`, followed by some number of `change` events.

I need to reliably trigger my processing logic only once, when the archive is finished being transferred. How can this be done?

Additional notes:

- I am not able to make changes to the system sending the archive, only
  the system receiving it.
- I am not considering using elapsed time to
  guess that the scp event has concluded. That is not reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the watch library you can do:

```
var watch = require('watch')
watch.createMonitor('/home/path', function (monitor) {
   monitor.on("created", function (file, stat) {
       // do work with new file
   })
}
```

I recommend taking advantage of the rich library ecosystem available to you because you're using the node platform.  Some of these problems have already been solved for you!

Comment: Very cool. I was not aware of this library. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This doesn't actually address the problem -- the watch module just wraps `fs.watch`.  The `created` event is directly equivalent to the `rename` event OP already observed -- we're right back to having the same problem.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but it only seems to be generating 1 event per file

Comment: @DonaldASubert: Sure -- `created` == `rename`, and you only saw one `rename` event didn't you?  For the reasons [I describe below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37200383/201952), acting when you get the `created`/`rename` event means you will try to process a file that is most likely incomplete since it is still being uploaded.

Comment: But part of the output is the file size, which shows the correct size of the full file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that file transfers are not instantaneous; the series of events you have observed make complete sense:

1. Someone begins uploading a file.  The scp server creates a new file.  Your watcher sees the `rename` event.
2. Bytes are sent to your server.  The scp server writes them to the file from step 1.  Your watcher sees many `change` events.
3. The upload completes.  No further events are generated because all the bytes have been written.

As far as I know (and based on skimming [the source of scp](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c)), there is no way to configure the scp server to do something when an upload actually completes.  This leaves you with two options:

- Debounce the `change` events.  This means setting a timer every time you get a `change` event and clearing the previous timer.  Eventually, you'll stop getting events, the timer will fire, and you can assume that the upload is complete.

  This does leave you vulnerable to acting on stalled or aborted uploads.
- You could implement your own scp server.  [This gives a good overview of how the protocol works.](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works)  The remote scp simply opens a ssh connection and runs the host's `scp` command, which then has a simple protocol for file transfer.  You'd have to replace your server's `scp` with your own implementation.

  Since the protocol tells you how many bytes to expect, you would know exactly when you've received the complete file and can begin your processing.